# How do i install Andy the android emulator on Linux?

Tags: 16.04, wine, android

I can't find a tutorial about this for whatever reason, so does anybody know how to install Andy? I have pretty much all the software I think I would need (Virtual box, an Android ISO,Andy.EXE which I tried running using wine) so if anybody could help me or provide me with a good tutorial that would be great. (i also saw a few tutorials on how to dual boot Android, I don't want to do that before anybody suggests it). I'm not a total newbie and I feel comfortable with the terminal, I can edit some things using VIM, I can find my why around the file system, I have written a scrypt before, etc but please don't suggest anything super complicated.

Comment: As Andy OS does not support Linux natively, you can try Anbox https://github.com/anbox/anbox for better support and performance.

Comment: @digiwizkid Really? I was told that it does, I can't remember where but I swear I was told it supports Linux. Are there any Linux compatible emulators that are more intended for gaming?

Comment: No officially they don't, see https://www.andyroid.net/ I am not sure about gaming but you can try Anbox

Comment: @digiwizkid I just found where I saw it http://aptgadget.com/best-android-emulators-linux/ but I guess it doesn't support Linux then, a bit later I'll try Anbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a virtual machine to set it up. You can download the Oracle VM VirtualBox from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

After downloading and installing the virtual machine properly

create a virtual machine and install ANDY OS... easy as rocket science.

There is also an alternative to use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) which is also wine-able, but I don't use it so I can't vouch for it's stability.

Comment: Too late, I already did just that. But since you are correct I will accept your answer :)

Comment: did you install an OS on the virtual box or you just installed the app?

Comment: Which one did you do? Installed VirtualBox and Andy OS on it or installed Genymotion instead?

Answer (score 2):

They state that here is a linux version in the making.

in [this](http://techapple.net/2014/05/5-best-android-emulators-linux-run-android-apps-linux-ubuntulinuxmintfedoraarchlinuxopensusemageiacentos-etc/) article the download link takes me to a plain text page where it says:

"Andy doesnt run on a mobile device, The Linux version is closed for Alpha if you want to join the testers please email alpha@andyroid.net or visit us again after July 30"

July 30 of what year I don't know, i'm gonna send em a mail for joining the alpha testing group

I did a more extensive search and found that the [system requirements](https://www.andyroid.net/faq/minimum-requirements) say it's compatible with Ubuntu 14.04 and up also I noticed they removed a reference to linux in [this](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi806b005XXAhUKnRoKHWR2CigQFghGMAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.andyroid.net%2Fandy-best-alternative-genymotion.html&usg=AOvVaw3qr1AxRJVDgdI_kgHiAoSq) article, google still shows the old text..

I will post a update when they get back to me to let you know what the current standing is.

Edit: Genymotion is what I would recommend for the time being. Do keep a eye out for Andy tho Genymotion is very good but it is aimed at developers, if you want you can read the last link I posted they explain some differences there.