# Can I Bluestack or Memu emulator use my Laptop?

Tags: android-emulator, ubuntu-emulator

I have 100GB SSD in my laptop. RAM: There is a pocket. CPU: Intel Celeron N3050 (2) @ 2.160 This processor is fitted. GPU: Intel Atom / Celeron / Pentium Proc. And I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS now. There I can play games.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What Android emulators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118903/what-android-emulators-are-available)

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU [is capable of running virtualization software](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/87257/intel-celeron-processor-n3050-2m-cache-up-to-2-16-ghz.html), though you will quickly see its limits. BlueStacks [requires Windows](https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056129211-System-requirements-for-BlueStacks-5), and [so does MEmu](https://www.memuplay.com/blog/system-requirements.html). If you wish to create a virtual environment on Ubuntu, [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) is an option.